# Schedule the system to poweroff

Tags: lubuntu, 15.04, shutdown

Is there a way to schedule my Lubuntu laptop to power off itself in say, one or two hours?

Which tool (or script) would be best suited for a standard installation of Lubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From command line :

```
sudo shutdown -h 23:30
```

The computer will shut down at 23h30.

```
sudo shutdown -P 45
```

The computer will shut down in 45 minutes.

---

Graphical solution : [EasyShutDown](https://launchpad.net/easyshutdown/trunk/0.6/+download/easyshutdown_0.6_all.deb)

[image]

Comment: does it work to schedule i.e. "in 45 minutes" instead of having to specify an exact clock time?

Comment: Yes ;) see my edited answer.

Comment: Great! But should it not be "+120" or is the plus sign not needed?

Comment: The plus sign is not needed.